# If $q>p$ then $H^q([0,2\pi])$ is dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$>

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I'm reading a book where it says that if $q>p$ then $H^q([0,2\pi])$ is dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$, and that this is due to the fact that the trigonmetric polynomials are dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$.

I know how to show that the trigonmetric polynomials are dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$, but I don't know how to formally use this to get that $H^q([0,2\pi])$ is dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$. If 'feels' like this is a true statement, but I really would like to show it?

Comment: Can you clarify your notation? What is $H^p$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. $H^p([0,2\pi])$ for $0\le p < \infty$ is the Sobolev space of all functions $\varphi \in L^2([0,2\pi])$ such that $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(1+n^2)^p|\hat\varphi_n|<\infty,$$ where $\hat \varphi$ are the Fourier coefficients of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of trigonometric polynomials. Clearly $P$ is a subset of each Sobolev space. You've got a proof that $P$ is dense in $H^p([0,2\pi])$, so can you prove the second inclusion of $$P \subset H^q([0,2\pi]) \subset H^p([0,2\pi])?$$
Since $P$ is dense so is the middle space.

Comment: Due to the denseness of the trigonometric polynomials in the Sobolev spaces, if we take the closure we get $\overline P = H^q([0,2\pi])$ and $\overline P = H^p([0,2\pi])$ which seems to imply $H^p([0,2\pi]) = H^q([0,2\pi])$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, the topologies are different. That's why the notation $\overline P$ doesn't make sense by itself - you need an ambient space containing $P$ where the closure is taken.